# Joomla Article Title (pdf, print icons) display incorrectly

Tags: php, apache, joomla, joomla1.5

I have been fighting with a strange bug. I could not figure it out since long.
This is a Joomla Website works totally normal on local server (WAMP). It also work normal on Godaddy server.

But currently i started using HostGator server. It displays the article titles incorrect. Title and PDF,print,etc icons don't get styling, they just display random.

I tried to turn on/off some php components on server. but could not figure out why title are not displaying correctly on server.

Check the screenshot bellow.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the URL for this so we can see the markup/css?

Comment: sure, here it is  http://umiyasansthan.com/en/aboutus

Answer (score 0):

The table that contains the 2 icons has three columns (and one row). First is the title, the next two are for the two icons...for those second two columns, the width is set to 100%. That's your problem. If you update the template and set those to just "20" instead of "100%" it will look fine.

Comment: Its doesn't solve the problem. Because this lines are generated by php code. so i dont have direct access to modify them. And they work on other server. must be some server or php config related problem.